# Is "lock up" a phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I heard the phrase:

> Don't forget to lock up.

in a movie. I think the person who said it meant to close all doors. I know what the word "lock" means but when we add that preposition "up" it seems to change the meaning totally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a phrasal verb.

It can be used *transitively* (Lock up the prisoner. Lock up all your valuables.)

Or it can be used without an object, which seems *intransitive* (as in the movie)  It's really just short for "lock up [everything/whatever needs to be locked]. But it is almost a separate idiom that looks identical to, but behaves differently than the transitive phrasal verb.

Good job catching that distinction!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the verb *to lock up* is a phrasal verb, more specifically: a **particle phrasal verb**.

Phrasal verbs are verbs that come with one or more other parts (particles and/or prepositions) and form one semantic unit. The meaning of the pieces can often not be understood separately, just as *up* in *lock up* does not really mean anything on its own.

There are two types of phrasal verbs: **particle** phrasal verbs and **prepositional** phrasal verbs.

Prepositional phrasal verbs take a *prepositional phrase*, which is **not the case here**. The *up* in your verb does not act as a preposition. Allow me to show you:

> - Did you **lock up** *the shop*?
> - Yes, I **locked** *it* **up**

A prepositional phrasal verb will always have the preposition in initial position within the prepositional phrase, even with pronouns:

> - Who's **looking after** the kids?
> - John's **looking after** *them*.

Here, *after the kids* and *after them* are prepositional phrases and the verb *to look after* is a prepositional phrasal verb.